# div.selector versus selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

In css, I have seen both div.selector and selector being used to define styling rules for a specific selector.

What's the difference between the two and what are the reasons I should consider when adopting one over the other when writing my own css files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `div.selector` targets only `div` elements with a class of `selector`.
- `.selector` targets ALL elements with a class of `.selector` not just `DIVs`

So prefix element with tag name if you KNOW that's the one you will be applying css to. The later approach is more ***generic*** and targets all elements with specified class. However, you should  be **specific** whenever you can.

*If you know only `div` elements will have `.selector` class*, going specific is better in terms of performance eg `div.selector` rather than `.selector` which will look for all elements on the page but will eventually apply those styles to `DIVs` only.

Comment: From my understanding, going specific is not better in terms of performance because the browser's rendering engine has to check to see whether the element which has the class applied to it is in this case a 'div' element.

This mozilla article highlights this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS

Answer (score 3):

`div.selector` is a more specific selector than `.selector`.

For example of you have this HTML:

```
<a href="" class="selector">Link</a>
<div class="selector"></div>
```

The selector `div.selector` only matches the div where `.selector` selects both elements.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned so far, prefixing your class with its element name (ie: div.selector) will select only elements which are divs, but exclude anything else. With this in mind you can create classes which can be applied to multiple elements and/or target a single element.

In terms of readability, prefixing your classes can help you and your team identify what the element is from within the css. However in terms of general best practise and performance it is commonly advised that you try to refrain from prefixing your class and id declarations as it causes additional work for your users' browser engine.

By prefixing your classes (ie: div#selector or div.selector) your browser has to locate the class and then identify whether it is of the div type). Whilst the time required to do this might be negligible, I feel it's still worth mentioning.

Below are a few helpful links on the matter of performance and practice:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS and 
http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/